# Get all object properties from delegate array

Tags: iphone, arrays, delegates, tableview

I am successfully retrieving an array from my delegate, however I am struggling to get all of the objects properties, so in my `AppDelegate`:

```
    arrayOne = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *tempArray1 = [self myArray];
// Add names to arrayOne
    for (MyInfo *info in tempArray1) {
        [arrayOne addObject:info.name];
    }
```

I then retrieve this in my `MainView`:

```
    cell.textLabel.text = [delegate.currentlyUsedArray objectAtIndex:row];
```

This works fine, but `myArray` contains other properties such as: `info.age` and `info.height` — how do I get these to another `textLabel`? Do I have to do the same approach as above or is there a more efficeint way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why can't you just add `info` to the array.

```
for (MyInfo *info in tempArray1) {
    [arrayOne addObject:info];
}
```

and later where you are setting it.

```
MyInfo *info = (MyInfo*)[delegate.currentlyUsedArray objectAtIndex:row];
cell.textLabel.text = info.name;

// Other fields should also accessible directly such as info.age and info.height.
```

Answer (score 0):

medley,
You can make method of appDelegate `myArray` public and get your info values right from where you need it, in this case in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Comment: Hi Zapko, thanks for the reply, sounds good... So I make `myArray` public in `AppDelegate` then will I also need to make it public in `MainView`? Then in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I should be able to get `myArray.info` and `myArray.age` etc...? Thanks for your time!

Comment: And also, how would that look in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`? Would it be something like: `cell.textLabel.text = [delegate.myArray.info.name objectAtIndex:row];`? Thanks again!

Comment: yeah, i suppose it will look something like:`cell.textLabel.text = ((MyInfo *)[delegate.myArray objectAtIndex.row]).name`

Answer (score 0):

Following Zapko's answer, your code in MainView would look like this to access the various properties of a MyInfo object in the myArray property of your delegate object:

```
cell.textLabel.text  = [(MyInfo *)[delegate.myArray objectAtIndex:row] name];
cell.ageLabel.text   = [(MyInfo *)[delegate.myArray objectAtIndex:row] age];
cell.heigtLabel.text = [(MyInfo *)[delegate.myArray objectAtIndex:row] height];
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! I chose Deepak's solution but your response was also very helpful, as was Zapko's... I would upvote you all if I could!!!